# Problem with updateData() function from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, compiler-errors

Here is my code for updating a field in my Firestore DB:

```
private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func moveToNextWeek(){
    let newWeekOn = plan!.weekOn + 1
    db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("Plan").document("plan").updateData(["weekOn": newWeekOn])
}
```

However I keep getting the error: `Ambiguous use of 'updateData'`.
I don't see why this error keeps coming up, any ideas?

Comment: Your code works for me. Force unwrapping optionals can be dangerous `plan!` and `currentUser!` so it may be a good idea to check that before attempting to write it as if it's nil, your code blows up.

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed by assigning it to a variable and adding `.description`.

`let _ = db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "NO USER").collection("Plan").document("plan").updateData(["weekOn": newWeekOn]).description`
However, I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Is this an answer? If so, it's not going to work well and there's no reason to do that (either assigning it to a var or adding .description). You will have signifiant issues leaving the code that way. I would continue looking elsewhere because the code in you question is legit and works correctly.